# TreeView из XML

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net, treeview

Как програмно в asp.net сгенерировать TreeView из xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно сделать так:

**aspx:**

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
    <Nodes>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Products">
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Hardware" />
            <asp:TreeNode Text="Software" />
        </asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="Services" />
    </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

**code:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
        TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode("Consulting");

        // Добавить в качестве дочернего узла второго корневого узла
        // (узла Services в предыдущем примере)
        TreeView1.Nodes[1].ChildNodes.Add(newNode);
}
```

Больше примеров в [статье](http://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/sites/level2/2_5.php).

UPDATE:

Пошаговое руководство по загрузке из xml-документа [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7a9swst5(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Это не то, что мне нужно, но за интересную статью спасибо.

Comment: Добавил статью по работе с xml-документами...

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
            XmlNode xmlnode ;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("tree.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            xmldoc.Load(fs);
            xmlnode = xmldoc.ChildNodes[1];
            treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xmldoc.DocumentElement.Name));
            TreeNode tNode ;
            tNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
            AddNode(xmlnode, tNode);
        }

        private void AddNode(XmlNode inXmlNode, TreeNode inTreeNode)
        {
            XmlNode xNode ;
            TreeNode tNode ;
            XmlNodeList nodeList ;
            int i = 0;
            if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
            {
                nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes;
                for (i = 0; i <= nodeList.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];
                    inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));
                    tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes[i];
                    AddNode(xNode, tNode);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                inTreeNode.Text = inXmlNode.InnerText.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Источник: http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/treeview-from-xml.htm

Comment: Спасибо за сооучастие в процессе, но это гайд для winforms - я такое в интернете тоже видел. А вот где найти аналог для asp.net не знаю.